# python check first column name and retrieve input from excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, telegram-bot

I'm working on a script with telegram bot and python.

I need help with regarding how can i retrieve int from excel while checking first column name matches session_name ?

Currently it is manually key in by user as the following code

```
session_name = 'adder1' 
startFrom = int(input("Start From = "))
endTo = int(input("End to = "))
```

However, i want to simplify things and let python read from excel rather than users manually key in the numbers.
For example, with the following excel, I want python to enter to check `session_name = 'adder2'` then confirm and will input `startFrom = 41` and `endTo = 80` rather than human input.
This is necessary for me as I have a lot of scripts to change if doing manually, so doing an excel sheet will be much easier for me.

[image]

Edit :

```
df = pd.read_excel('mytable.xlsx')

startFrom, endTo = df.loc[df['Session'].str.contains(session_name, case=False),
                          ['Start', 'End']].squeeze()
n = 0

for user in users:

    if ( int(startFrom) <= int(user['srno'])) and  (int(user['srno']) <= int(endTo)):
```

Shows errors *An illegal target for a variable annotation* and *Statement expected, found Py:RBRACE*

Comment: Hint: on the line `if ( int(startFrom) <= int(user['srno'])) and  (int(user['srno']) <= int(endTo)):`, how many `(` are there? How many `)` are there? Do you see why this causes a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas` (`pip install pandas` or `conda install pandas`)

```
session_name = 'adder2'

df = pd.read_excel('mytable.xlsx')

startFrom, endTo = df.loc[df['Session'].str.contains(session_name, case=False),
                          ['Start', 'End']].squeeze()
```

```
# session_name = 'adder2'
>>> df

  Session  Start  End
0  Adder1      1   40
1  Adder2     41   80
2  Adder3     81  120

>>> startFrom
41

>>> endTo
80
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, ```startFrom, endTo = df.loc[df['Session'].str.contains(session_name, case=False),['Start', 'End']].squeeze()``` This shows me error of 'End of statement expected' and my code below ``` if (int(startform) <= int(user['srno'])) and (int(user['srno']) <= int(endto)): ```  is showing An illegal target for a variable annotation occured

Comment: Edit your post with your (new) snippet of code.

Comment: any idea why this few errors are showing? @Corralien

Comment: What is the value of `users` please?

Comment: ```user = []```

Comment: Sorry Corralien i think it works now, syntax error i fixed.

Comment: any idea why my code suddenly having this error *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Start'* at code ```for user in users:

    if ( int(startFrom) <= int(user['srno'])) and  (int(user['srno']) <= int(endTo)):```